# Windows Low-Level Graphics

Tags: api, winapi, graphics, directx, gdi

I'm new to programming. I do know C/C++ and the basics of Win32. I am now trying to do graphics, but I want the fastest connection to the screen. I realize most are going with Opengl or DirectX. But, I don't want the overhead. I want to start from scratch and control the pixel data. I know about GDI bitmap, but I'm not sure if this is best access to the data. I know that I have to talk through windows, which is the trouble. Do Opengl and DirectX compile down to the level of GDI or is there a special way they do it, do they bypass or use similar code? Please, Don't ask why I want to do this. Maybe an explanation of how this is done might help. Like how windows combines all windows to create the final image.

Comment: Great. A "I have no clue how my computer or my OS works, but I've already decided on all the ways in which I do NOT want to solve my problems, and please don't ask me why I ruled out all the efficient approaches" question. Those are the best

Comment: You can use nvapi for nvidia GPUs... Please refer documentation.
https://developer.nvidia.com/nvapi

Answer (score 8):

The most direct access to pixel data is via *shaders*, which are supported by both OpenGL and Direct3D.  They are cross-compiled and run directly on the video card.  They do not use OpenGL, they do not have OpenGL overhead.  OpenGL is just used to get them to the graphics card's own processor in the first place.

Anything you do on the CPU has to first be copied across the bus (typically PCI-express) to the video card.  GDI is actually many levels removed from the graphics memory.

OpenGL, Direct3D, Direct2D, GDI, and GDI+ are all abstraction layers.  The GPU vendor writes a driver that accepts these standard command functions, re-encodes the data in the card-specific format, then sends it to the card.  Typically OpenGL and Direct3D are the most heavily optimized and also require the least amount of re-encoding.

How Windows combines the various on-screen windows to create the full-screen image depends heavily on what version of Windows you are talking about.  DWM changed *everything*.  Since DWM was introduced in Vista, programs render to their personal areas of GPU memory, then the window manager uses the texture lookup units of the video card to efficiently layer each of the programs' individual areas onto the screen primary buffer.  When a program (usually a game) requests full-screen exclusive access, this step is skipped and the driver causes rendering commands from that application to affect the primary screen buffer directly.

Assuming that the CPU is generating the data which needs to be displayed, the fastest and most efficient approach is likely to be block-copying that data into a vertex buffer object and using OpenGL commands to rasterize it as lines or polygons or whatever (or the Direct3D equivalent).  If you previously thought that GDI was the low-level interface, you've got some reading ahead of you to make this work.  But it will run several orders of magnitude faster than pure GDI.  So much faster, in fact, that the new architecture is that GDI (and WPF) is built on top of Direct2D and/or Direct3D.

Comment: Thanks that was a great response. I have one more question. I don't know if my line of thinking is correct, but I have thought that the GPU was addon to increase processing of that type of manipulation. And there was another video card part of the motherboard that then connects to the screen. Like my laptop has a Nvidia card. And I thought it  CPU -> GPU -> integrated video card -> Screen and could bypass GPU making it addon. Not that I want to. I'm also thinking of committing to CUDA just for opt. the parallelism.  Does everything go through nvidia and it controls the screen directly?

Comment: @user1364455: GPU is part of the video card.  With hybrid systems it's not quite as nice as what I wrote.  The drawing is done on the GPU, then the framebuffer is copied back to the integrated graphics for streaming to the screen.  Unless your graphics are very simple, this is still faster than using the integrated graphics, and much more power-efficient than using the CPU to generate the image.  Anyway, you can ignore your nvidia chip -- everything I wrote applies to the Intel integrated graphics too, the newer Intel chips (like Sandy Bridge) even support shaders on the integrated graphics.

Comment: @user1364455: The point is that in modern computers there's code that runs on the processor that's directly attached to graphics memory that provides data to the screen, and THAT PROCESSOR IS NOT THE CPU.

Answer (score 1):

> but I want the fastest connection to the screen
>
> I want to start from scratch and control the pixel data

You're asking for the impossible. You get best performance when you use GPU-accelerated functions. However, in this case you don't get direct access to pixel data, and trying to access it (read it back or write) will negatively impact the performance, because you'll have to transfer data from system memory to video memory. As a result anything that is being streamed from system memory to video memory should be handled with care. Plus you'll have to study API.

If you "start from scratch" and do rendering on CPU, you'll get easy access to pixel data and full control over the rendering, but performance will be inferior to GPU (CPU is less suitable for parallel processing, and system memory can be slower by order of magnitude than video memory), plus you'll spend significant amount of time reinventing the wheel.

> Do Opengl and DirectX compile down to the level of GDI or is there a special way they do it, do they bypass or use similar code?

No. They communicate with graphic hardware nearly directly using drivers provided by hardware manufacturer. And those "direct hardware access" interfaces used by DirectX/OpenGL won't be available to you - they're hardware-specific and manufacturer specific, can be internal and possibly even protected by patents.

There are, of course, few legacy hardware interfaces which ARE available to you (namely VESA or VGA 13h mode), however, their direct use is normally forbidden by operating system (you can't easily access VESA on windows), so to access them you'll have to either boot MS-DOS, use custom operating system, or helper classes (such as SVGAlib on linux) which might only function under root privilegies. And of course, even if you actually use VESA/VGA to render something yourself, on any hardware (newer than RivaTNT 2 Pro) performance will be horrible compared to hardware-accelerated rendering done by OpenGL/DirectX. Have you ever seen how fast windows xp works when it doesn't have proper GPU driver (takes a second to redraw window)? that's how fast it is going to work with direct VESA/VGA access.

> Please, Don't ask why I want to do this.

It makes sense to ask why you would want to do that. Your "I want direct low-level access" approach was suitable maybe 15..20 years ago or in DOS era. Right now reasonable solution would be to use existing API (that is maintained by somebody who isn't you) and search for a way to fully utilize it. Of course, if you wanted to develop drivers, that would be another story.

Answer (score 0):

> Do Opengl and DirectX compile down to the level of GDI or is there a special way they do it

and

> I realize most are going with Opengl or DirectX. But, I don't want the overhead

So what you're saying is **you have absolutely no clue what OpenGL or DirectX actually do, and yet you've decided that they are not efficient enough for your needs.

I'm sorry, but this is nonsense. It is impossible to answer a question like that.

In the real world, you have a small supercomputer dedicated to doing graphics. And you get access to it through OpenGL and DirectX.

And the reason they are fast is that they do **NOT** just "start from scratch and control the pixel data".

So please, if you want serious answers, try letting those with the knowledge to answer your questions decide which question is best.

The correct answer, if you want efficient graphics, is to use DirectX or OpenGL.